# Limit maximum number of errors

Tags: eslint

How to limit maximum number of error in eslint through .eslintrc. My current .eslintrc

```js
module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    "max-warnings" : 2
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `max-warnings` is a command-line only option. You can't define it in a `.eslintrc` file. See [eslint#2769](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2769).

There are a couple of alternatives you can use, depending on how you are runnning eslint. You can use something like [eslint-nibble](https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble) to address a subset of the errors one at a time, and see that subset.

Another option if you're using a task runner is to use its built in options. For example, if you're using `gulp-eslint` you can fail on/after the first error using [failOnError/failAfterError](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint#eslintfailonerror):

```
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    gulp   = require('gulp');

gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```