# ng lint how to use eslint CLI flags such as --max-warnings=0

Tags: angular, angular-cli, eslint

I've got an Angular 10 project that uses eslint.

I run my linting with:

```
ng lint
```

There are no errors but some warnings. I want `ng lint` to fail with a non zero exit code when there are only warnings. I've tried using the eslint flag --max-warnings=0 as follows:

```
ng lint --max-warnings=0
```

but it says:

> unknown option '--max-warnings'

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917828/1205871) suggests --max-warnings is an eslint CLI option only and cannot be configured via an .eslintrc file

How can I force linting to fail when there are only warnings when running `ng lint`? Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`--max-warnings 0` try this. The `=` is not required.